# hibernate second level cache using jboss cache in clustered environment

Tags: java, spring-3, hibernate3, jboss-cache, jboss-eap-4.3.x

hi i am using following in my project

1. jboss server(4.3 EAP) in 'all' configuration
2. spring 3.0
3. hibernate 3.0
4. jboss cache 1.x

snippet of **applicationContext.xml to enable second level cache** is

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider
        </prop>
    </props>
    </property>
```

snippet of **applicationContext.xml for transaction manager** is

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

content of **treecache.xml** is

```
<server>
    <classpath codebase="./lib" archives="jboss-cache.jar, jgroups.jar" />
    <mbean code="org.jboss.cache.TreeCache" name="jboss.cache:service=MyTreeCache">
        <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
        <depends>jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>
        <attribute name="TransactionManagerLookupClass">
            org.jboss.cache.GenericTransactionManagerLookup 
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="ClusterName">MyPartition</attribute>
        <attribute name="NodeLockingScheme">PESSIMISTIC</attribute>
        <attribute name="CacheMode">REPL_SYNC</attribute>
        <attribute name="IsolationLevel">REPEATABLE_READ</attribute>
        <attribute name="FetchInMemoryState">false</attribute>
        <attribute name="InitialStateRetrievalTimeout">20000</attribute>
        <attribute name="SyncReplTimeout">20000</attribute>
        <attribute name="LockAcquisitionTimeout">15000</attribute>
        <attribute name="ClusterConfig">
            <config>
                <UDP loopback="true" />
                <PING timeout="2000" num_initial_members="3" up_thread="false"
                    down_thread="false" />
                <FD_SOCK />
                <pbcast.NAKACK gc_lag="50" retransmit_timeout="600,1200,2400,4800"
                    max_xmit_size="8192" up_thread="false" down_thread="false" />
                <UNICAST timeout="600,1200,2400" window_size="100"
                    min_threshold="10" down_thread="false" />
                <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="20000" up_thread="false"
                    down_thread="false" />
                <FRAG frag_size="8192" down_thread="false" up_thread="false" />
                <pbcast.GMS join_timeout="5000" join_retry_timeout="2000"
                    shun="true" print_local_addr="true" />
                <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER up_thread="true"
                    down_thread="true" />
            </config>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

and starting the node with following command

**run.bat -c node11 -g MyPartition -u 239.255.100.100  -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default**

then it is throwing **following exception**

```
18:51:16,303 ERROR [TreeCache] Caught exception registering channel in JXM
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.jgroups:type=protocol,cluster=My
tition,protocol=STATE_TRANSFER already registered.
        at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.add(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:
)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegi
y.java:225)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java
3)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOpe
ionInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:376)
        at org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator.registerProtocols(JmxConfigurator.java:108)
        at org.jboss.cache.TreeCache.registerChannelInJmx(TreeCache.java:6730)
        at org.jboss.cache.TreeCache._createService(TreeCache.java:1477)
        at org.jboss.cache.TreeCache.createService(TreeCache.java:1389)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport
va:260)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.create(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:188)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.
a:280)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.start(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider.start(TreeCacheProvider.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory
calSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFacto
LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertie
t(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
vokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
itializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
eateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(Ab
actBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSi
eton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Abst
tBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(Abstra
eanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAut
reCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResol
ependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolve
endency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
or$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(Inject
Metadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
or.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
pulateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
eateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(Ab
actBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSi
eton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Abst
tBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(Abstra
eanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInst
iateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFac
yInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(Abstr
ApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicat
Context(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(Cont
Loader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(Con
tLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:
4)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4348)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:7

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5263)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDepl
r.java:295)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.jav
08)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.
a:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupp
.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.jav
78)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy53.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java
3)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOpe
ionInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:9
        at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServic
eanSupport.java:238)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerIntercepto
ava:87)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(S
eployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.ja
95)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy54.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java
3)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOpe
ionInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanne
ava:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.
a:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(
tractDeploymentScanner.java:266)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(Abstract
loymentScanner.java:344)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.
a:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupp
.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.jav
78)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java
5)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java
3)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOpe
ionInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:26
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:518)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
18:51:18,639 INFO  [STDOUT]
```

what is wrong i am doing here can some one suggest me.
any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you have 2 jgroups clusters setup (the cluster for the app server and the cluster for the treecache) and both clusters have the same partition name "MyPartition".  You need to configure a different partition name for the treecache cluster config.